# How to create a 'url_for' link helper in AngularjJS

Tags: url, routes, angularjs, angularjs-routing

In .NET MVC there is `@Url.Action()` and in RoR there is `url_for()`

I could not find similar url building helper in angularjs.

I'm already providing everything that is needed to build url to `$routeProvider` so something like: `$routeProvider.urlFor("MyCtrl", {id: 5})` could be nice to have.

My main goal here is to avoid hardcoded urls in viewes and other places and to avoid repeating url/routes patterns twice.

UPDATE:

Seems like it's hard to explain what i want so here is exact example of what i want:

Instead of writing this in viewes:

```
<a ng-href="/product/5">foo</a>
```

I want to write this:

```
<a ng-href="urlFor("ProductCtrl", {id:5})">foo</a>
```

So if later i decide to change path of ProductCtrl I would not have to update url in this a element.

What would be good solution for my goals?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try with something like the following (just came up with it) inside your main module's run() block:

```
app.run(function($route, $rootScope)
{
  $rootScope.path = function(controller, params)
  {
    // Iterate over all available routes

    for(var path in $route.routes)
    {
      var pathController = $route.routes[path].controller;

      if(pathController == controller) // Route found
      {
        var result = path;

        // Construct the path with given parameters in it

        for(var param in params)
        {
          result = result.replace(':' + param, params[param]);
        }

        return result;
      }
    }

    // No such controller in route definitions

    return undefined;
  };
});
```

This will extend the root scope of the application with the new path() function - so it can be used anywhere in the application. It uses the $route service to get the controller names and the corresponding paths, so you won't have to repeat yourself.

Example usage:

```
{{ path('LibraryController', { bookId : 'x', chapterId : 'y' }) }}
```

Live example at: http://plnkr.co/edit/54DfhPK2ZDr9keCZFPhk?p=preview

Comment: This solution struggled when multiple routes used the same controller.  I updated it to find the first route where the passed params satisfy the required params, and then I changed the order of my routes to make sure the most specific routes were defined first. Also updated to Angular 1.2.21.  Thanks for the solid starting point @mirrormx! Code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/05ilcKRf3Zcm1XXYhz9i?p=preview

Comment: Yes! now how do we push this to the next version of angular?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous approaches...a custom `directive` or `ng-click` to modify `$location`, or using a function in `ng-href` to parse the url from object and have it placed as `href` in an `<a>` tag.

Example using `ng-href`:

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-href="{{url(item)}}">{{item.txt}}</a>
</li>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope){
  $scope.items=[
    {id:1,txt:'foo'},
    {id:2,txt:'bar'}
 ];

  $scope.url=function(item){
    return '#/'+item.id
  }
}
```

Example using `ng-click` and `$location`

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="newPath(item)">{{item.txt}}</a>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope){
  $scope.items=[
    {id:1,txt:'foo'},
    {id:2,txt:'bar'}
 ];  

  $scope.newPath=function(item){
   $location.path('/'+item.id)
  }  
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ovemaq/3

Comment: My main goal is to avoid hardcoded urls in viewes and other places and to avoid repeating url/routes patterns twice. you example repeats route pattern that was already written/configured in $route

Comment: not clear what your question is then. Provide a demo that outlines issue more clearly, or a better explanation. `$routeprovider` will manage changes to url, but highly likely view will have to make the actual changes based on user interaction

Comment: In .NET MVC there is @Url.Action() and in RoR there is url_for(). I want same functionality in angular. It is helper method that would use your routes configuration to give you links to your controllers.

Comment: ok..so question is about automatically defining `controller` within `$routeProvider`? You can use variables in path in `$routeProvider` if that helps. Need to create a demo that shows where your problem lies

Answer (score 1):

In one of recent project I came up to this solution it helped me to solve my needs right in time. It will be interesting to help you to improve it to fit your usecase.

**1.** Move routes definition to config:

```
...
ROUTES: {
    PAGE1: '/page1/:id',
    PAGE2: '/page2/:id/:name'
},
...
```

**2.** Define routes, using values from config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'config', function ($routeProvider, config) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when(config.ROUTES.PAGE1, {
        templateUrl: 'partials/page1.html',
        controller: 'PageOneCtrl'
    });

    ...

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

**3.** Set up service to provide functionality to create urls:

```
services.factory('routes', function (config) {

    // populates `:param` placeholder in string with hash value
    var parseString = function (string, parameters) {
        if (!string) return '';
        if (!parameters) return string;

        for (var index in parameters) {
            if (!parameters.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;

            string = string.replace(':' + index, parameters[index]);
        }

        return string;
    };

    return {
        getPage1Link: function (urlParams) {
            return '#' + parseString(config.ROUTES.PAGE1, urlParams);
        }
    };
});
```

---

**== Drawbacks ==**

With this approach I had to define getter for each route (there were less then 5, and development speed was vital)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want is the ui-route directive which has just been recently added to the [angularui project](http://angular-ui.github.com/). There is a nice set of out-of-the-box options.

Comment: ui-route looks interesting, but looking at examples i don't think it is what i want. It looks like i have hard time trying to explain what functionality i'm after, i will update question with more info.